# Parallax H1 and H2

Tags: javascript, html, css, parallax

Can someone tell me how to adjust this .js? I want it to be able to apply on H1 and H2 with an ID in my html. Now it is only working on css background-image. Below is the .js I'm using. I'm a beginner with javascript;)

Hope you guys can help me out!

```
    (function( $ ){
    var $window = $(window);
    var windowHeight = $window.height();

$window.resize(function () {
    windowHeight = $window.height();
});

$.fn.parallax = function(xpos, speedFactor, outerHeight) {
    var $this = $(this);
    var getHeight;
    var firstTop;
    var paddingTop = 0;

    //get the starting position of each element to have parallax applied to it      
    $this.each(function(){
        firstTop = $this.offset().top;
    });

    if (outerHeight) {
        getHeight = function(jqo) {
            return jqo.outerHeight(true);
        };
    } else {
        getHeight = function(jqo) {
            return jqo.height();
        };
    }

    // setup defaults if arguments aren't specified
    if (arguments.length < 1 || xpos === null) xpos = "50%";
    if (arguments.length < 2 || speedFactor === null) speedFactor = 0.1;
    if (arguments.length < 3 || outerHeight === null) outerHeight = true;

    // function to be called whenever the window is scrolled or resized
    function update(){
        var pos = $window.scrollTop();              

        $this.each(function(){
            var $element = $(this);
            var top = $element.offset().top;
            var height = getHeight($element);

            // Check if totally above or totally below viewport
            if (top + height < pos || top > pos + windowHeight) {
                return;
            }

            $this.css('backgroundPosition', xpos + " " + Math.round((firstTop - pos) * speedFactor) + "px");

        });
    }       

    $window.bind('scroll', update).resize(update);
    update();
};
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be `background-position`. Can you try changing?

```
$this.css('background-position', xpos + " " + Math.round((firstTop - pos) * speedFactor) + "px");
```